# No users with ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql, permissions

I've encountered an issue after upgrade of MySQL server.
Probably, upgrade procedure went south.
The result was that none of the users had **ALL PRIVILEGES** grant.

All the administrators had *GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, TRIGGER ON* and *GRANT OPTION*

It looks very much like *ALL PRIVILEGES* translated into individual privileges, but obviousely something is missing. After reviewing the privileges listed, i've found that all the users were missing **EVENT** privilege.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE Event_priv='Y'\G
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Now, this privilege [was added in MySQL 5.16](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_event) and is defined as `enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'`, so probably `UPDATE` on existing users have failed (or is missing in the upgrade scripts).

After realizing what was wrong, i started to look for a solution here (I mean, if **NO** user has this privilege, how do i `GRANT` it?), and did not find a problem exactly like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i thought i'd ask, but then i thought "*wait a second, what if...*"  and attempted to `UPDATE` the users table myself... and VOILA! MySQL actually LET ME do it!

So here it is:

**Question**: How to recover a missing EVENT privilege?

**Answer**:

```
 mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Event_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)
```

Then login again to MySQL and that's it - `SHOW GRANTS` shows root having `ALL PRIVILEGES` again.

---

So (and this is my guess, correct me if i am wrong), as long as you still have `UPDATE` privilege that affects mysql privilege tables, you can pretty much grant any privilege to yourself or others by manually).

I'm sure this is *conceptually* OK (since i do have `UPDATE`...), but as a side note i'd say this is kinda weird that i can alter my own privileges to a larger set.

Comment: +1 for finding your own answer !!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of the [*--skip-grant-tables*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) MySQL startup option - it allows for bypassing the permission checks for recovery purposes. A daemon started with this option would allow a root login without a password with ALL PRIVILEGES granted. You can change anything you like from there on.

Note: as running with a passwordless root account is likely to present a security risk, you should make sure to specify *--skip-networking* as well.

Comment: This would require restarting a database server though (twice - second time to get back to normal state), which is time consuming, and means downtime

Comment: But this is worth mentioning, of course ;) so +1

Comment: @poncha - If it would be just for the privileges, you would need to restart only once - a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` would re-read the mysql.users table and put the privileges back in effect. Of course, since you're starting with skip-networking and do not want any succeeding connection attempts in the meantime anyway (they would get rejected due to failed authentication), this would actually mean restarting twice. On the other hand, it is a generic approach working with any kind of privilege / authentication problems.